# Sharing/feed link to app, that works on mobile?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

The mobile version of the apps are nice, but it doesn't seem to affect the shared links on the timeline. I get 4oh4.php when I click it on mobile devices.

Is there a smart way, other than a redirect??

Thank you in advance.